# Checking if object is default value

Tags: c#, generics, null, equals

I have a generic method:

```
Public bool Insert<T>(object data) 
{
Bool isEmpty()=> ?
}
```

I need to check if data = default(T). T could be a list, int, datetime
Any ideas?

Comment: `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(data, default(T))` (just `Equals(data, default(T))` would do it, but that unnecessarily boxes value types)

Comment: We've found some other questions which ask the same thing which already have great answers, so we've added links to those other questions and prevented people from adding yet more answers here. It's OK that you didn't manage to find these yourself: it's a lot easier to find related questions when you know what the answer is!